# NotificationCenter obersever not called

Tags: swift

I have UITabBarController and two ViewControllers.
In the first vc I have a video, after it ends the data transfer to another controller is triggered. But unfortunately nothing happens in the second controller.

```
func fetchCaloriesData() {
    refWorkout = workout!.title
     Database.database().reference().child("programs").child(refWorkout).child("calories").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        self.caloriesData = snapshot.value as! String
        print(self.caloriesData)
        self.dictionary["calories"] = self.caloriesData
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "sendCalories"), object: nil, userInfo: self.dictionary)
        print("Заполнили словарь")
        print(self.dictionary["calories"])
        //self.caloriesDelegate?.update(newText: caloriesData)
       
       // self.dietVC.BurnedLabel.text? = caloriesData
         
     }
 }
```

Everything is work. When I try print I can see: Optional ("...")
In second vc in viewDidLoad I have next code.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(gotNotification), name: NSNotification.Name("sendCalories"), object: nil)
```

and next

```
 @objc func gotNotification(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
        guard let calories = userInfo["calories"] as? String else {return}
        print("Наблюдатель")
        print(calories)
        BurnedLabel.text! = calories
    }
```

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Find out the difference between `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @ElTomato 
I've tried all three options. Nothing works

Comment: One mistake: guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(gotNotification)
this will be called only if view is loaded before notification is triggered,
so you need to pass data in different way when you tapped to open second view controller. After that observer is in on state, so he is monitoring changes. Basically if you downloading something asynchronous and that is not finished while you open second view controller, after that if downloading is done, your second view will be updated, be sure to update UI on main thread. In your case make variable with calories object in second controller, then from first controller update main tab bar controller(add calories property there as well) with delegate method(make protocol to pass calories) so you don't shoot notification everywhere and from there update second controller.
That is how you will have fresh data always.

```
guard let firstController = controllers[0] as? FirstController else {return}
   firstController.caloriesDelegate = self

guard let secondViewController = controllers[0] as? SecondController else {return}
   secondViewController.calories = self.calories // in main tab bar after updating
```